# Отсчет обратного времени, и закрытие формы

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

как сделать так, чтобы при открытии формы TestForm
начался отсчет 15:00:59 15:00:58 и т.д. чтобы время это отображалось в label2
и когда 15 мин. вышли, то форма просто закрылась автоматически.

Запускать таймер должна форма TestForm

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4 {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
            button1.Click += button1_Click;
        }

        void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            StartTimer();
        }
        void StartTimer() {
            TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(3, 0, 0);
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                while (ts.Hours!=0) { 
                    label1.Invoke((Action)(() => { label1.Text = ts.ToString(); }));
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    ts = ts.Subtract(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1));
                }
                //Тут ставим действие по окончании таймера.
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: используйте асинронный цикл

Comment: @tym32167, если бы я знал как. вопроса бы не задал... как его сделать то?

Comment: После ответов на 500+ вопросов и нескольких лет, потраченных на этот сайт, я уже не делаю никаких выводов о том, что человек знает, а чего не знает, это бессмысленно :)

Comment: @tym32167, оформите ответ, ибо я не знаю. и некоторые пояснения.

Comment: да, я сйечас вам накидаю пример, не переживайте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простейший пример с асинхронным циклом будет выглядеть вот так

```
public class MyForm : Form
{   
    public MyForm()
    {
        var label = new Label();
        this.Controls.Add(label);
        Countdown(label);
    }

    private async void Countdown(Label lbl)
    {
        var start = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var end = start.AddSeconds(15);
        var diff = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);        

        while((DateTime.UtcNow - start) < diff)
        {
            lbl.Text = (diff - (DateTime.UtcNow - start)).ToString();
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }

        Close();
    }
}
```

Проверка

```
var form = new MyForm();
form.ShowDialog();
```

Результат

[image: ...]

Я сделал отсчет на 15 секунд, но вы легко можете поменять это на 15 минут.

Comment: спасибо Вам за помощь

Comment: @zert пожалуйста, на здоровье

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно так сделать

```
namespace project
{
    public partial class TestForm : Form
    {
        public TestForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Load += (sender, args) => StartTimer();
        }

        private async void StartTimer()
        {
            TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0, 15, 0);
            while (ts > TimeSpan.Zero)
            {
                label2.Text = ts.ToString();
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                ts -= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            }
            Application.Exit();
        }
```